# Ant Design 4.23 using conditional tabs

Tags: typescript, antd

I've just recently upgraded my project's Ant Design version and I need to replace how my tabs are rendering from

```
<Tabs>
  <Tabs.TabPane tab="Weight" key={Routes.WeightStats}>
   //....
  </Tabs.TabPane>
```

to

```
<Tabs items={[
  { label: 'test', key: 'test', children: <>test</>
]} />
```

However I have a some conditionals in my tabs previously:

```
<Tabs.TabPane key="test1">
  // ....
</Tabs.TabPane>
{currentUser.hasXyz && (
  <Tabs.TabPane key="test2">
    // ....
  </Tabs.TabPane>
)}
```

I'm trying to translate this over to the new Tabs API but my conditional doesn't work:

```
<Tabs items={[
  ...(currentUser?.hasXyz && {
     label: 'test',
     key: 'test',
     children: <>test</>,
  }),
]} />
```

The error I get is

```
Type '"" | { label: string; key: string; children: Element; } | null | undefined' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
```

I can get around this with casting `any` but I want to avoid that. Is there a workaround?

Comment: why are you spreading object?

Comment: I looked up how to do conditional fields within an object and stumbled on this: https://amberley.dev/blog/2020-09-07-conditionally-add-to-array-or-obj/

Comment: even  without TS try JS, that isn't valid syntax: `[
  ...(true && {
     label: 'test',
     key: 'test',
  }),
]`

Comment: `(currentUser?.hasXyz && {
     label: 'test',
     key: 'test',
     children: <>test</>,
  })`

can return null and you cannot use spread operator for a null. 
`(currentUser?.hasXyz ? {
     label: 'test',
     key: 'test',
     children: <>test</>,
  } : {})`

can work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Tabs items={[
    { label: 'test', key: 'test', children: 'test' },
    ...(currentUser?.hasXyz ? [
        {
            label: 'currentUser?.hasXyz is true',
            key: 'yay',
            children: 'content',
        }
    ] : []),
]} />
```